# process_sdp: Can't provide secure audio requested in SDP offer

Tags: sip, asterisk, webrtc

I cannot make a call from Chrome browser to an Asterisk machine in which WebRTC is configured. What should I do? (see details)
I am getting a warning while calling, i.e `WARNING [7087] [C-00000005]: chan_sip.c: 10648 process_sdp: Can't provide secure audio requested in SDP offer`.

Comment: Found this googling: http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=86433

Comment: and https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=491

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, But I have seen this link. It didn't solve my problem. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with your environment (WebRTC or Asterisk)... from my basic SDP understanding, WebRTC is requesting to use secure audio channel (SRTP), but it is getting rejected from the receiving end... My initial thoughts would be to 1) Make sure that the Asterisk is supporting SRTP (first link) or 2) Try to disable SRTP from WebRTC (second link).

Comment: Asterisk is not support SRTP. So you have use webrtc client without srtp or use kamailio

Comment: I have installed SRTP module from sourceforge , and while executing make menuselect it show that SRTP has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC defines the requirement of SRTP with DTLS. In asterisk you need to compile it with res_srtp module. Make sure it's loaded:

```
module load res_srtp.so
```

And add it to the sip peer with WebRTC:

```
transport = ws,wss
encryption = yes
```